# Correct placing the AngularJS ng-repeat and expression in bootstrap table

Tags: html, angularjs

Where should I place `ng-repeat` directive  and `{{expression}}` in the  to get numbers from 1 to 7, in `<td>`, correctly (I have placed them by hand now), for the following code:

```
`<h1> January 2017 </h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr class="active">
        <th> # </th>
        <th> Sunday </th>
        <th> Monday </th>
        <th> Tuesday </th>
        <th> Wednesday </th>
        <th> Thursday </th>
        <th> Friday </th>
        <th> Saturday </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="other">
        <th class="active"> 1 </th>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
        <td> 4 </td>
        <td> 5 </td>
        <td> 6 </td>
        <td> 7 </td>
    </tr>
</table>`
```

Comment: it should be like this


     `<td ng-repeat="">{{}}</td>`

Comment: @ Hadi Jeddizahed it worked. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) you have "the proper way" explained. In the section "Tracking and Duplicates" you can see a example:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

that in your situation can be translated into:

```
<td ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
  {{n}}
</td>
```